# Bootstrap.js - Make root columns break before nested columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

I created a simple grid system using bootstrap.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6>
            <div class="row">
                <div class=col-lg-6>
                    Nested Column 1
                </div>
                <div class=col-lg-6>
                    Nested Column 2
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
             Root Column 2
        </div
    </div>
</div>
```

Now I'd like to make Root Column 2 break before the Nested Columns break into new lines when the screen resolution changes.

```
_____________________
|         |         |
| N1 | N2 |    R2   |
_____________________
```

Resolution changes =>

```
___________
|         |
| N1 | N2 |
___________
|         |
|    R2   |
___________
```

Resolution changes again =>

```
_______
|     |
|  N1 |
_______
|     |
|  N2 |
_______
|     |
|  R2 |
_______
```

Comment: You can follow the link http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/

Answer (score 2):

It's just a matter of setting the col definitions for each screenresolution. Bootstrap works in xs, sm, md and lg screens:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6>
            <div class="row">
                <div class=col-md-6>
                    Nested Column 1
                </div>
                <div class=col-md-6>
                    Nested Column 2
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
             Root Column 2
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Setting the nested column to md-6 instead of lg-6 should do the trick, which corresponds to:
col-xs-12, col-sm-12 col-md-6, col-lg-6

if you only set the col-lg-6 it corresponds to:
col-xs-12, col-sm-12 col-md-12, col-lg-6
which means when the screensize changes to md, it will have 100% width (12/12 columns)

Read more about bootstrap 3 grid system here:
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm  BUT I'm using the class "row-eq-height" to make all rows equally height. The problem there is that when I'm using this class my root columns won't ever break into a new line,

Comment: I dont think flex is fully supported by bootstrap yet. I would suggiest writing a javascript solution for it instead to be able to keep full responsive layout.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/vasanthanvas/ktd31mne/

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    Nested Column 1
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    Nested Column 2
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12">
             Root Column 2
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```